# What does Anna mean when she says that she lost her whistle 133 days ago?

Tags: dialogue, prisoners

What does Anna mean when she says that she lost her whistle 133 days ago in *Prisoners*? It just seems too specific coming from a child. And what does Mrs. Dover whisper to everyone right after it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sorry if this is a partial answer (I'll delete it if you think it's not up to standard), but for what it's worth, the [script](http://pdl.warnerbros.com/wbmovies/awards2013/screenplay/prisoners/prisoners_sp.pdf) eludicates what Grace said:

> ANNA: The emergency whistle Daddy gave me. I lost it... (thinking) Hundred and thirty-three days ago.
>
> GRACE: **She’s just like her father.**

So Anna remembering the exact day is supposed to demonstrate her similarity to her father. However, I'm not quite sure *how*. Maybe because he's good with numbers as a carpenter? Has a good memory? Notes certain things others don't or can't let them go? (Then again, I don't remember much of this film, so maybe commenters can enlighten me on how this is also one of Keller's character traits.)

Comment: I agree with this. Its part of her characterization. Keller is a very prepared and precise individual and it would make sense that he would have a child with some similar traits.

Comment: Yeah. This might as well be  the correct explanation. Makes sense. Thanks @Walt

Comment: I just thought of something else too. The loss of her whistle might have meant to serve as a foreshadow of Keller losing Anna. Maybe I'm overthinking it though.

Comment: Her mom says "she's just like her father" because the daughter's mention of the exact number of days suggests she has inherited her dad's anxious and obsessive-compulsive nature (evidenced by his survivalist fears and the organization of his basement).

Answer (score -1):

I found this answer on [Yahoo](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20130929200640AAr7GGW):

> Q 1. Why was there (coincidentally) a whistle down under the trans am?
>   Did Anna drop it there "133 days" ago?
>
> A 1. The girls were initially kept in that hole in the ground under
>   the Trans-Am while the police searched the aunt's house for the girls.
>   Anna must have dropped her pink whistle there. Her mother later bought
>   her a new red whistle to replace the one lost. Joy and Anna had made
>   it to Anna's house and Joy had found the first whistle so the girls
>   were abducted on route back to the Birch's house.

My guess is that at some point, as most prisoners do, she began counting days in captivity.

Comment: No. You didn't understand. She said that she lost her whistle before the kidnapping, during the Thanksgiving dinner.